# Authorize user on the basis of username in webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization, httpcontext

I want to apply permission on some method using **[Authorize]** in Web Api, on the basis of the logged in username.

```
[Authorize(Users = "Alice")]
public ServiceResult<List<DefaultCities>> GetCitiesByZipCode(String zipcode)
{
}
```

In place of **"Älice"** i want to give username of the basis of **CurrentLoggedInUserId**.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a custom authorize attribute?

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Authorization logic
        if(httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Equals("Alice"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
         //Handle unauthorized logic
    }
}
```

And then attach that custom attribute to a controller

```
[MyAuthorization]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About() {}
    public ActionResult Contact() {}
}
```

The `AuthorizeCore`-method will run each time you call an action in `HomeController`.

If however you don't want the authorization to run for specific actions, you can annotate them with `[AllowAnonymus]`

```
[AllowAnonymus]
public ActionResult Home()
{
    //Everyone can run this action
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Not working.... this custom attribute is not being called.
What i might be doing wrong?

Comment: I updated some code and added additional information

Comment: Still not able to call AuthorizeCore.

Comment: Have you tried to set the authorization attribute above your controller definition and set a break point at the start of `AuthorizeCore`?

Comment: Yes I did, but the debugger is not hitting.

Comment: I am using Web api, can that be a reason?